# should I use MySQL procedure for this query?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, random

I want to make stored procedure but I don't know what should be the right approach or if this is even possible to do in MySQL.

Let me introduce you with my problem. Let's say I have table that has columns like this:

```
TABLE A
id  | Hotel  |  city_name  |  region_name  | country
 1  |   A    |   Amsterdam | North-Holland | Netherlands
 2  |   B    |   Amsterdam | North-Holland | Netherlands
 3  |   C    |   Leiden    | North-Holland | Netherlands
 4  |   D    |   Katwijk   | North-Holland | Netherlands
 5  |   E    |   Leiden    | North-Holland | Netherlands
 6  |   F    |   Katwijk   | North-Holland | Netherlands
```

I would like to get only 3 results each time I execute this query and results need to be created in this order:

1. If there are 3 or more cities ( user selects in this case we can take Amsterdam ) that `city_name=Amsterdam` then return random 3 cities in Amsterdam
2. If there is less then 3 records in Amsterdam return any of the record that has Amsterdam + return random records where `region=North-Holland` but the total amount of the records that are returned should always be 3 ( **example:** we have 2 records where `city= Amsterdam` + we take one random record from `region=North Holand;` 
   **example2:** we have one record where `city=Amsterdam` + we take 2 random records where `region="north Holland"`)

Is that possible to this with the SQL Or should I get all the records in php and then iterate through each of the records?

I probably need to pass 2 arguments in the procedure (city_name, region ).

So far I have tried some basic SQL queries and I couldn't get it to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try something like

```
(SELECT *
FROM A
WHERE city_name = 'Amsterdam'
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 3)

UNION

(SELECT *
FROM A
WHERE region = 'North Holand' AND city_name <> 'Amsterdam'
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 3)

LIMIT 3;
```

Comment: Ah, that would work too, but you'll need to exclude the city_name 'Amsterdam' in the second SELECT or you might end up with the same record from the first SELECT

Comment: WHERE region = 'North Holand' AND city_name <> 'Amsterdam'

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you do the logical part of this primarily in php.  While it is possible to do in sql, I've found that logic structures in sql tend to be hard to follow, and that is less of an issue in php.

Doing the logic in php could require two separate queries (but only if you don't get 3 initially).

I'd run a query to get the initial three (use `LIMIT 3` in the sql).  Check to see if you got three results.  If you didn't, subtract the amount you do get from 3, then use that as the `LIMIT` in a second query to get the other random results.